# Using neo4j database in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, neo4j

I'm working on an webserver project with tomact. I have a dataBase in neo4j. How can I link it to the dataBase? I want to get information from there and also add new data, in the servlets that I created. I tried running the dataBase in the background But i still get "Forbidden (403) - Forbidden" in my project. Do I have to set it somehow? I'm using eclipse, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

// ...

public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphDatabaseFactory graphDbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("path_to_neo4j_database/your_database_folder");
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            // use graphDb object to manipulate the DB content
            tx.success();
        }
        graphDb.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Done :) ");
}
// ...
```

And don't forget to add the Neo4j library to build path:

[image: don't forget to add the Neo4j library to build path]